# How can I make a function that calls another function every 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function:

```
isAuthenticated = (): boolean => {
    xxx
};
```

I am using AngularJS and I would like to know how can I make a function such as

```
keepCheckingAuthentication()
```

That will call the is Authenticated() function every 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably use `$interval` function (wrapper of `window.setInterval()` in AngularJS)?

The documentation of `$interval` function is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

In your case `keepCheckingAuthentication()` is the function and you can adjust the other parameters accoding to your needs? Does this help?

example:

```
$interval(myFunctionAtInterval, 5000) // Scheduled for every 5 seconds, for instance

funtion myFunctionAtInterval() {...}
```

Comment: @ha - Can you give me an example and also what would the difference be between setInterval and $interval?  Thank you

Comment: @Alan           there's no difference...it's a wrapper....I have corrected my answer....

Answer (score 2):

There’s a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function that will call any code with given time interval in ms:

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() { console.log('Works!') }, 1000);
```

Later you can cancel the timer using `clearInterval(intervalID)`.

Answer (score 2):

If `isAuthenticated` can be modified to actually make a request to call the server in order to check authentication, and can return a promise that resolves or rejects when this is done, then I would do something like

```
var keepCheckingAuthentication = function() {
  return isAuthenticated().catch(angular.noop).then(function(isAuth) {
    // Can do something different if isAuth == false
    return $timeout(keepCheckingAuthentication, 60 * 1000);
  });
});
```

Note the call to `catch`. This effectively converts any rejections to a success, so the next `then` callback runs in every case.

Using something like this rather than `$setInterval` means there will always be 60 seconds between responses from the server, rather than requests made. On a slower connection, or an overloaded server, this means there is a lower chance of adding to the overloaded connection or server, as you're sure the previous request has finished before sending off another one.

Comment: Out of curiosty: why using the `catch()` and `then()` combination instead of just using `finally()` instead? `Finally` will fire in case of both positive and negative response. Wouldn't it make for a cleaner code or am i missing something? Anyway good answer indeed, you get my upvote.

Comment: @Nobita I think you're right that it would be a bit cleaner in this case. However, the `finally` callback doesn't get passed the resolved/rejected value from the promise. Depending on what you want to actually do when the user isn't authenticated, that might be useful. I've edited the question to hint that.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid `setInterval` whenever I can, i.e. always (Paul Irish talks about this in this [video](https://youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg?t=7m45s)).

What I do is wrap a `setTimeout` in a function that recursively calls itself (with a condition that allows me to easily stop, or to let the data decide when it's not needed anymore).

```
var condition = true;

$scope.count = 1;

function myFunc(){
   $scope.count += 1;
 }

var timer = function(){
  myFunc();
  if( condition ){
    $timeout(timer, 1000);
  }    
};

timer();
```

I am using angular built in `$timeout` here as it's always suggested.
A [demo](http://jsbin.com/famiso/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In the video he avoids `setInterval` because the callback might take longer than the interval to run, resulting in nasty situations. Since the interval here is 60 seconds, I don’t think that’s such a problem, unless there are other reasons against `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

use $interval.this code will help you:

```
var callefunc=function() {
    console.log('hey i am calle');
}

$scope.caller=function(){
    var stop = $interval(callefunc, 1000);
}
```

here you can call a `caller` function when you want to start function `callefunc` on interval of 1 second .